# PHP curl questions

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$url = 'www.google.com.my';
$header = true;
$returntransfer = true;
$connecttimeout = 3;
$timeout = 60;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returntransfer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $connecttimeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

$execute = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $execute;

echo "\n\ncurl_getinfo() said:\n", str_repeat('-', 31 + strlen($url)), "\n";
foreach ($info as $label => $value)
{
    printf("%-30s %s\n", $label, $value);
}
echo str_repeat('-', 31 + strlen($url));
?>
```

Here is my questions:

(1) I want to test the web services using PHP curl. Am I missing something based from the above code?

(2) If I have 2 URLs, should I use `curl_setopt` or `curl_multi_init`?

I really hope that someone will answer my questions.

Comment: Should use curl_multi_init() and curl_setopt is neccessary too. check contents about curl.

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt I have edited my code. Please have a look.

Comment: @MichaelKuan did you want multiple url open simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a simultaneous requests:

```
$ch_1 = curl_init('http://url.one.com/');
$ch_2 = curl_init('http://url.two.com/');
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// build the multi-curl handle, adding both $ch
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch_2);

// execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
$running = null;
do {
curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running);

// all of our requests are done, we can now access the results
  $response_1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_1);
$response_2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch_2);
echo "$response_1 $response_2"; // same output as first example
```